# Cython unordered_map variant value

Tags: cython

So, in a nutshell, I'm trying to get something like this working:

```
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map
cdef unordered_map[unicode, variant] test
```

variant is of course not something cython recognizes. 
I have these unordered maps which I'd like to contain; as value; either another unordered map or a python object.

The depth of these maps varies and the value type may change later.
Can this at all be done or am I stuck with python dicts?

I was hoping to be able to release the gil during traversal of the tree.

Comment: I think `std::variant` can't work b/c cython currently doesn't support non-type template params, but could try something like Boost.Variant or similar?

Comment: I had quick look at `std::variant` and don't see why it wouldn't work (at least large chunks of the interface), but you'd have to wrap it yourself. Storing a Python object would require some reference counting (and the GIL, for when it's accessed). I'd be tempted to write some C++ and wrap that rather than trying to do the whole thing in Cython

Comment: The project is not currently using boost and I don't want to bring in the rather large requirement. As for writing a C++ wrapper, as I only know C and even that only really from school, that would take too long to learn.

So, they're great recommendations for those who can use them, which is not really me.

Comment: Having thought about it some more, I don't see how this can be done just using the c++ standard library. The map type needs to know the variant type as a template parameter but the variant type also needs the map type as a template parameter, leading to an infinitely long template name. Something like is almost certainly possible, but I'm not sure exactly how.